# *Calendar Program* Having trouble writing a loop for this calendar program to display properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

I am having an issue trying to complete my code. I am trying to get the code to print the arrays in several different rows. It is suppose to look like this:

[image: Calendar]

Ok, here is the updated code. I have been working on it and it is getting better! However, my issue now is trying to figure out what I need to do in order to create blank spaces where the "0" and "1" are currently in the output of the code. I think I just need to insert:
    calDaysOfWeek.unshift();
or possibly:
    calDaysOfWeek.shift();
I just cannot figure out where to put it. If I can figure that out, I should be able to make the days in my code less abbreviated (Such as M to Mon or T to Tues).

```
/*Write a program called calendar.js that displays a calendar month 
for May 2012 as the month and year. You must use a loop. The format 
of the month should be as shown below: Hint: You can't use console 
log and print on the same line. Try storing the entire row as one 
concatenated string and then displaying it. You must use loops for 
this one. Do not just print the calendar as a series of console.log 
statements!*/


calDaysOfWeek = [];
calDaysOfWeek.push("Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat");

var s = "MAY 2012\nS M T W T F S\n";

var numDaysOfWeek = calDaysOfWeek.length;
var firstDay = 2;
var numDaysOfMonth = 31;
var numWeeks = numDaysOfMonth/7;
for(var i = 0; i < numWeeks; i++) {
 for(var j = 0; j < numDaysOfWeek; j++) {
    s += i*numDaysOfWeek + j + ' ';
}
s += "\n";
}
if (firstDay != calDaysOfWeek[2]) {
calDaysOfWeek.push();
}
else if (calDaysOfWeek[30] != 31) {
    calDaysOfWeek.pop();
}
else
    console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an error here:

```
for(var i = 0; len = calDaysOfWeek.length; i < len; i++)
```

It should be:

```
len = calDaysOfWeek.length; 

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

}
```

Now, you need to use this loop to fill your string rather than using arrays. So:

```
var s = "";
len = calDaysOfWeek.length; 

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

}
```

But your loop is only going from 0 to 6 since you have 7 days of week. So you need another loop for the weeks. Something that you cannot compute easily is the first day of the month which is a Tuesday, so it's indice in calDaysOfWeek is 2 (Sun=0, Mon=1, Tue=2). You also need the number of days in the month, here 31.

```
var s = '';
var numDaysOfWeek = calDaysOfWeek.length;
var firstDay = 2;
var numDaysOfMonth = 31;
var numWeeks = ??? // compute this
for (var i=0; i<numWeeks; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<numDaysOfWeek; j++) {
         s = ??? // you need to do this
    }
}
```

Once the result is correct you can display it by using html code that you will print.

Edit: changed the loops

Edit2: played with it on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/synkkbo2/3/)

```
calDaysOfWeek = [];
calDaysOfWeek.push("Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat");

var s = "MAY 2012\n";
var numDaysOfWeek = calDaysOfWeek.length;
var firstDay = 2;
var numDaysOfMonth = 31;
var numWeeks = 5; // compute this
for (var i=0; i<numWeeks; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<numDaysOfWeek; j++) {
         var n = i * numDaysOfWeek + j + 1 - firstDay ;
         if (n < 1 || n > numDaysOfMonth) {
               s += '   '; // three spaces
         }
         else {
             if (n < 10)
             {
                 s += ' '; // pad with one space
             }
             s += n + ' ' ;
         }
    }
    s += "\n";
}


alert(s);
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift response. Although, I am still confused. I believe "5" would be the calculation for "numWeeks" but I don't get what the "s" variable is for. I also don't believe we are using html code in my class. I have only used console.log to display output.

Comment: In your case numWeeks is indeed 5, if you wanted to compute more generally from firstDay and numDaysOfMonth then you can find a number between 4 (28 days with the month beginning a Sunday) to 6 (31 days with a month beginning a Saturday)...You can hardcode it to 5 if you don't feel like computing it. The var s is the string that will receive the result, you should be able to use only 1 console.log() to display s.

Comment: @MagnetM, try something like this in the inner loop: `s = s + i*numDaysOfWeek + j + ' ';`That's not the final answer but it should get you closer.

Comment: Should the "s" variable be an array?

Comment: s is a string.  If you want you can make an array of string to store each line.Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/synkkbo2/) to get you started. I need to go now but I'll check back tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the help so far... I will be working on it.

Comment: Now you need to fix the errors by using if () else () and firstDay and numDaysOfMontrh

Comment: I am still having trouble if you are still checking this post Dominique. I tried implementing an if(), else if(), and else() statements but I am doing something wrong. I keep trying to use the calDaysOfWeek to specify the id location for firstDay in order to make an if statement but I am clearly doing it wrong. I updated my code above to show this.

Comment: Aha! This makes much more sense now, thank you so much for your help Dominique. If there is anything I can do to upvote you for credit or anything let me know

Comment: Well keep asking questions, maybe I'll answer another in the future XD I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I most definitely will, thanks again! Enjoy the rest of your Sunday!